# Can't change a single button's background color with sass on Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I'm trying to do something I would think most developers need to do with Ionic 3, which is customize an active tab color.

I've been through all the sass customization and the closest is:

```
$tabs-ios-tab-color-active
```

However, that just changes the icon.

If you change the background, it changes the entire bar and not a single button.

Does anyone know the proper override for this?

Comment: _If you change the background, it changes the entire bar_ can you show what you attempted for this?

Comment: Hi Suraj, it's in my post. I added the tab color 'active' mixin.

Comment: i didnt tried it...but seems like it will work...    `.tabs-positive > .tabs{
background-color: red !important;
}`
try this in your page scss.